# How to append to a list by matching elements row by row in a python data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

New to python,I have data frame as below:

```
A         B   
10      [4,12,20]
12      [20,15,33,65]
14      [5,11,18]
```

My goal is to:

1. Loop through the list in column `B`
2. Check if the value in column `A` for that list exists in any other list under column `B`
3. If a match is found (EG: Row `0` detects `A Value: 10` exists in row `1` column `B`)
4. Combine the rows column `B` together (EG: `0` and row `1` column `B` and save it under column `C`, ignoring duplicate values)

Output:

```
A         B                    C
10      [4,12,20]       [4,12,20,33,65]
12      [20,10,33,65]   [20,4,12,33,65]
14      [5,11,18]       [5,11,18]
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve from your explanation. Your expected output doesn't match with what you are explaining.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [10,12,14]
B = [[4,12,20], [20,10,33,65], [5,11,18]]
C = B[:]
d=dict()
for z in zip(A,B):
  d[z[0]] = z[1]

for i in range(len(B)):
  match = set(A) & set(B[i])
  if match:
    for m in match:
      C[i] = (list(set(C[i]) | set(d[m])))

print(C)  # [[33, 4, 65, 20, 10, 12], [33, 20, 65, 4, 10, 12], [5, 11, 18]]
```